# New Raspberry Pi 4 default password 'raspberry' incorrect

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I have just brought a new Raspberry Pi 4 and I have been following the guide below to connect to the Pi using ssh, but when I was asked for the password, the default password 'raspberry' is apparently incorrect?

Guide: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/06/09/raspberry-pi-laptop-display/

I have tried format (NOT quick) the sd card and install the OS again but I am still getting the same problem, can anyone help, please?

Thanks in advance!

Update: Using RaspController on my android phone, I was able to connect to the Pi using ssh and I now have VNC setup on both my phone and laptop. However, access is still denied when trying to connect ssh via PowerShell on my laptop to the Pi. I am assuming this has to do with Window's firewall? But I am not sure what settings need to be configured. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Ubtuntu Server 2020 from the Raspberry Pi Imager, than the default credentials for SSH are different.
Try,
Username: `ubuntu`
Password: `ubuntu`